# Kepler third law for circular orbits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

This question may be uber trivial, but it has been stuck in my head for a while.

[Kepler's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law) states that the period of the orbit $T$ is related to the **semi-major axis** $a$ though
\begin{equation}
 T^2 = 4\pi^2\frac{a^3}{G(m_1+m_2)}.\tag1
\end{equation}
where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the masses of the two bodies.

Consider a simple system where $m_1 = m_2=m$ and the orbit is circular so $a$ is the radius.
[image]

Kepler's Law (1) tells us that
\begin{equation}
T^2 = 4\pi^2\frac{a^3}{2Gm}.\tag2
\end{equation}

---

If I wanted to derive this equation from the equation of motion of $m_1$, for example, I would write
\begin{equation}
G\frac{m_1 m_2}{(2a)^2} = m_1 a \omega^2.\tag3
\end{equation}
which in the case that $m_1 = m_2 = m$ reduces to
\begin{equation}
 \omega^2 = G\frac{m}{4a^3} .\tag4
\end{equation}
Considering that $T = 2\pi / \omega$, I obtain
\begin{equation}
 T^2 = 4\pi^2\frac{(2a)^3}{2Gm} .\tag5
\end{equation}

**Why do I have here the diameter instead of the radius as in equation (2)?**

### Two-body problem approach

If I approach the problem instead of looking at the motion of a single mass, but considering the **two-body** problem, the equation of motion should be
\begin{equation}
G\frac{m_1 m_2}{(2a)^2} = \mu (2a) \omega^2.\tag6
\end{equation}
where $\mu = \frac{m_1 + m_2}{m_1 m_2}$ is the reduced mass. Considering again $m_1 = m_2 = m$, the previous equation simplifies to
\begin{equation}
G\frac{m^2}{(2a)^2} = \frac{m}{2} (2a) \omega^2.\tag7
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to the equation of motion for the single body (3) and should lead to the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to apply Kepler's third law in the form

$\displaystyle \omega^2 = \frac {G(m_1+m_2)} {r^3}$

where $r$ is the radius of a planetary orbit, $m_1$ is the mass of the primary and $m_2$ is the mass of the secondary. However, this form only applies when $m_1 >> m_2$. If $m_1$ and $m_2$ have similar values then the appropriate form of Kepler's third law is the [binary mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_mass_function)

$\displaystyle \omega^2 = \frac {Gm_1^3} {(m_1+m_2)^2r_2^3}$

where $r_2$ is the distance of $m_2$ from the centre of mass. In you example, $m_1=m_2=m$ and $r_2=a$ so we have

$\displaystyle \omega^2 = \frac {Gm^3} {(2m)^2a^3} = \frac {Gm} {4a^3}$